# jQuery Validate: remote - everything works, but no error is shown

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to implement email validation using the Bassistance jQuery plugin, with a check if the email adress exists.

The remote script returns correcctly `true` or `false`, however - no error message is shown. Other validation (required, email) works fine.

Any idea's what I'm missing here?

The jQuery code:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#post").validate({
        rules: {
            lid_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote:  {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:"email-check.php"
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            lid_email: {
                required: 'Gelieve een geldig e-mailadres in te vullen.<br>',
                email: 'Gelieve een geldig e-mailadres in te vullen.<br>',
                remote: 'Dit adres bestaat reeds. Gelieve een ander adres te kiezen.'
            }
        }
    })
    jQuery('#lid_email').blur(function() {
        jQuery("#post").validate().element( "#lid_email" );
    });
});
```

And the remote script:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

$request = trim(strtolower($_POST['lid_email']));

if ( email_exists($request) == TRUE ) {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
} else {
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

- I'm using the script in a Wordpress site, and included wp-blog-header.php in order to have access to the Wordpress functions.
- Apparently the line `require('../../../wp-blog-header.php` breaks the json functionality
- If I remove this line, the booleans are sent correctly, and the error message shows up.
- All I have to do, is write my own user_exists-function, and then the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with:

```
echo (email_exists($request) === true )?'true':'false'
```

instead of:

```
if ( email_exists($request) == TRUE ) {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
} else {
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
}
```

I have a similar problem and I resolved in this way. Additionally, I commented to you that in this way I didn't need put a json header.

Comment: @ptriek But, have you noticed what happens in both cases when firebug return `false` or `true`?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned something strange is happening there. I checked using Charles proxy - and the strange thing is Charles reports a 404 - and yet returns the correct boolean. If I check with Firebug, it just reports a 404 - so I guess the problem is situated over there...
So maybe I should rephrase my question: any idea why the php script throws a 404?

Comment: @ptriek That so weird, I think you need review your path file or your htaccess.

Comment: I just found the solution, it's the wp-blog-header.php Wordpress script that breaks it. I've written an explanation of the problem/solution - but apparently my reputation is too low to answer my own question within 8 hours :-S 
So hold on :-) & thanks for your help